# How to customize Codeigniter Watermark text and Image using image library?

Tags: php, image, codeigniter

I have added watermark text and image during uploading image.

Watermark is added perfectly but issue with watermark size.

when I upload medium size image watermark is added perfectly but when I upload large size image watermark text and image appear very small. And if I upload small image then watermark will appear very large.

I want to add watermark on all images with similar size.

So any other configuration for watermark so that this issue will resolved.

Code :

```
    $this->load->library('upload');
    $this->load->library('image_lib');
    $config['image_library'] = 'GD2';

    for ($i = 0; $i < $number_of_files; $i++) {
        $_FILES['file']['name'] = $files['file']['name'][$i];
        $_FILES['file']['type'] = $files['file']['type'][$i];
        $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] = $files['file']['tmp_name'][$i];
        $_FILES['file']['error'] = $files['file']['error'][$i];
        $_FILES['file']['size'] = $files['file']['size'][$i];
        $config['source_image'] = $files['file']['tmp_name'][$i];
        $config['wm_text'] = 'Copyright example.com';
        $config['wm_type'] = 'text';
        $config['wm_font_size'] = '16';
        $config['wm_vrt_alignment'] = 'middle';
        $config['wm_hor_alignment'] = 'center';
        $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
        $this->image_lib->watermark();

        $config['source_image'] = $files['file']['tmp_name'][$i];
        $config['wm_overlay_path'] = './application/assets/images/example.png';
        $config['wm_type'] = 'overlay';
        $config['width'] = '50';
        $config['height'] = '50';
        $config['padding'] = '50';
        $config['wm_opacity'] = '100';
        $config['wm_vrt_alignment'] = 'bottom';
        $config['wm_hor_alignment'] = 'right';
        $config['wm_vrt_offset'] = '100';
        $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
        $this->image_lib->watermark();

        if (!$this->upload->do_upload("file")) {
            $errors++;
        } 
}
```

Comment: Can you know size of uploaded image, when adding watermark? If yes, then use size of watermark with percentages. E.g: `image.height/100 * (wm_height_percentage);` Watermarks size will be always changed with size of image. But will take same size on any image.

Comment: Thanks for your precious time, can you explore it more to use in my code ? i am new with Codeigniter. so please explain it where and to use it in my code and how to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        // Define it in configuration file. And call it
        // About configurations: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/config.html
        $wm_font_size = 16; // Watermark height (font size) contains 16% of image 

        $this->load->library('upload');
        $this->load->library('image_lib');
        $config['image_library'] = 'GD2';

        for ($i = 0; $i < $number_of_files; $i++) {
                $_FILES['file']['name'] = $files['file']['name'][$i];
                $_FILES['file']['type'] = $files['file']['type'][$i];
                $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] = $files['file']['tmp_name'][$i];
                $_FILES['file']['error'] = $files['file']['error'][$i];
                $_FILES['file']['size'] = $files['file']['size'][$i];
                $config['source_image'] = $files['file']['tmp_name'][$i];
                $config['wm_text'] = 'Copyright example.com';
                $config['wm_type'] = 'text';
                $config['wm_font_size'] = ceil($files['file'][image_height][$i]/100*wm_font_size);
                $config['wm_vrt_alignment'] = 'middle';
                $config['wm_hor_alignment'] = 'center';
                $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
                $this->image_lib->watermark();

                $config['source_image'] = $files['file']['tmp_name'][$i];
                $config['wm_overlay_path'] = './application/assets/images/example.png';
                $config['wm_type'] = 'overlay';
                $config['width'] = '50';
                $config['height'] = '50';
                $config['padding'] = '50';
                $config['wm_opacity'] = '100';
                $config['wm_vrt_alignment'] = 'bottom';
                $config['wm_hor_alignment'] = 'right';
                $config['wm_vrt_offset'] = '100';
                $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
                $this->image_lib->watermark();

                if (!$this->upload->do_upload("file")) {
                    $errors++;
                }
```

Comment: It's awesome mate, this is very useful. I want to also change font family and i am doing this `$config['wm_font_path'] = './application/assets/fonts/revicons.ttf';` but gives an error. can you help me ?

Comment: Sorry, it's not giving error. when added font path watermark is not adding to image .

Comment: Try this code when adding fonts. `if ( ! $this->image_lib->watermark()) 
        echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();` Does it show any error on browser?

Comment: `'./application/assets/fonts/revicons.ttf';` should be `'../application/assets/fonts/revicons.ttf';`

Answer (score -1):

`function doWatreMark($image){
        $this->load->library('image_lib');
        $config['source_image'] = BASEPATH.'../assets/portfolio/'.$image;

        $config['wm_overlay_path'] = BASEPATH.'../assets/images/watermark-icon.png';
        $config['wm_type'] = 'overlay'; 
        $config['wm_opacity']   = '48';
        $config['wm_x_transp'] = '9';
        $config['wm_y_transp'] = '9';

        $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
        $this->image_lib->watermark();
}`